# Strange white pixel lines on odd size of border

Tags: html, css

In the codepen link:
https://codepen.io/jonasschmedtmann/pen/zYNyMJL/256706a9de79baf1bd19abcb68e820d9
there is a strange pair of horizontal and vertical lines surrounding the ADD TO CART button at bottom and left sides respectively if you change the .product selector to `.product { border: 5px solid black; }`
.This is happening with every odd border size and the lines disappear when the border size is set to an even length. It is happening on chrome.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, please do not just dump the whole thing onto an external platform. See also: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: Which browsers is this happening on? It sounds like a well known issue when the system is mapping CSS pixels onto the (several) screen pixels - sometimes a screen pixel’s worth gets left behind’.

Comment: It's happening on chrome .